# Given $f \in V^*$ and $\mathscr A : V \to V$ a linear map, show that $f,f \circ \mathscr A,\dots,f \circ \mathscr A^{n-1}$ is a basis for $V^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, invariant-theory, invariant-subspace

Let $V$ be a $n$ dimensional vector space, $V^*$ is its dual, $\mathscr{A}$ is a linear transform from $V$ to $V$. Given $g\in V^*$, define
$$\mathscr{B}(g)=g\circ\mathscr{A}$$
Then it is easy to prove that $\mathscr{B}$ is linear trasnform from $V^*$ to $V^*$.

Let $f\in V^*$. Suppose that any nonzero invariant subspace of $\mathscr{A}$ is not a subspace of $\ker (f)$. Show that
$$f,\mathscr{B}f,\cdots,\mathscr{B}^{n-1}f$$
is a base of $V^*$.

My attempt: Let
$$k_0f+k_1\mathscr{B}f+\cdots+k_{n-1}\mathscr{B}^{n-1}f=0$$
then
$$k_0f(v)+k_1\mathscr{B}f(v)+\cdots+k_{n-1}\mathscr{B}^{n-1}f(v)=0, \,\forall\ v\in V$$
that is,
$$k_0f(v)+k_1 f(\mathscr{A}v)+\cdots+k_{n-1}f(\mathscr{A}^{n-1}v)=0, \,\forall\ v\in V$$
or equivalently,
$$k_0v+k_1\mathscr{A}v+\cdots+k_{n-1}\mathscr{A}^{n-1}v\in \ker f, \,\forall\ v\in V$$
How to proceed then?

Comment: Given $v\in V$, the generated subspace of $v,\mathscr Av, \dots,\mathscr A^{n-1}v$ is $\mathscr A$-invariant.

Comment: @azif00 How to do then?

Comment: Looks like this is just a convoluted way of expressing the concept of [Krylov-Subspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace).